# How to query from another Oracle Database

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Please can anyone suggest how can I query my from another oracle database, I need to update some column in the table from my database1, but first I need to get the data from another database. I'm passing my sql scripts using java.

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append("SELECT CUSTNAME,CREATEDDATE FROM custtbl");
stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query.toString());
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

I have some options in mind but don't know which one is more efficient.

here's my option :

1. Create a temporary table in the database1 and insert the data from database2. Then batch update certain table in database1 getting the values from the created temporary table.
2. Using db link. But I will need the DBA to create the links. Which can take days because of certain approvals needed.

Thank you!

Comment: even in option 1 how would "insert the data from database2" happen?. Its either through a db link or extract the data into a text file and load it from the text to database1. If this is a one time activity i would choose option 1

Comment: In general, option 2 should be more efficient (fewer steps), but option 1 (text file transfer?) is probably more secure. As George stated, it would help to know if this is a one-time thing or needs to be repeated, and approximately how much data we're talking about. Sounds like you're going to need the assistance of the DBA either way.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph thank you! also thinking of loading data from text file. But i need to run the script everyday..